# Jquery Ajax Form Submission: multiple forms - same button-id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, onsubmit

For now it seems to work without problems but I was wondering...Let's say you have multiple forms (each on a different page) with each and one of them a different id.

Each form has a button with and id "btnSave". In the masterpage (template) I added all links to the  ajax-formhandling-scripts working like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ignore the submit
    $("#frmNews").submit(function() {
        return false;
    });

    // catch the click-event
    $("#btnSave").on("click", function() {
        // input control
        // ajax-request if input was ok  
    }
});
```

Before I continue to build I want to know sure using the same button-id won't give me problems. Am I working wrong here?

Comment: Repeated `id` attribute values are invalid - they must be unique. Use a `class` instead.

Comment: "same ID" = alarm. You can't have the same ID. ID is a UNIQUE IDentifier. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeated `id` attribute values are invalid - they must be unique. Use a `class` instead. Also, from a design point of view you should hang all logic off the `submit` event of the `form`. Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ignore the submit
    $(".frmNews").submit(function(e) {
        // input control
        if (input_control_ok) {
            // $.ajax()...
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault(); // stop form submission
        }
    });
});
```

The `.btnSave` button should then have the `type="submit"` attribute added to it, assuming it doesn't already.

Comment: Thx for this useful tip! I see you use e.preventDefault but I often bump into tutorials where they suggest using e.defaultPrevented. Is e.preventDefault still better?

Comment: `defaultPrevented` is only a boolean property indicating if `preventDefault()` was used - they aren't the same thing.